# Why SearchView Background Selector Not Work According Focus

Tags: android, user-interface, colors, searchview

I tried to change the background of the search view according to whether it's focused or not.

This is my search view:

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/search_view_selector"
        android:theme="@style/SearchViewStyle"
        app:closeIcon="@drawable/ic_baseline_close_24"
        app:searchHintIcon="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
        app:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
        app:voiceIcon="@drawable/ic_baseline_mic_24"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
```

This is my selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="false" 
 android:drawable="@drawable/bg_search_view" />

<item android:state_focused="true" 
 android:drawable="@drawable/bg_search_view_focus"/>
</selector>
```

bg_search_view:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid android:color="#434343"/>
  <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
</shape>
```

bg_search_view_focus:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid android:color="#55B0D9"/>
  <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
</shape>
```

And its NOT work maybe someone know why?